# Qt error: "kit: Desktop Qt 5.5.1 MSVC2012 32bit"

Tags: c++, qt

I am new in Qt. I just downloaded Qt [open source](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/) and tried one of its sample projects (and also [a simple project](https://wiki.qt.io/Basic_Qt_Programming_Tutorial)) but I got the following error:

```
09:06:42: Configuration is faulty. Check the Issues view for details.
Error while building/deploying project qt-tutorial-01 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.5.1 MSVC2012 32bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

In Tools>Options>Build&Run>Kits there are some erros:

[image]

and

[image]

I couldn't find anything about this error and how to fix it. 
Is there any comment what should I do?

thanks in advance!

**EDIT1**

compiler tab:
[image]

and

[image]

I have Windows 7 Professional 64Bit and Visual Studio 2005 on my PC

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the "compilers" tab ?
Another question, are you sure you have the VS compiler installed on your system?

Comment: your Qt binaries are for Vs2012 and it detects only an older compiler ...

Comment: @ luffy please check edit1

Comment: @ Ziaborg: you mean I should install a newer version of VS (like VS express 2015)?

Comment: as Zaiborg said, It's detecting the wrong version of VS!
If you d'ont have to use VS you may want to try the mingw version:
http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.5/5.5.1/qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw492-5.5.1.exe

Comment: for vs2015 you would need the 2015 binaries ... so i suggest you use a newer compiler (preferable the version the binaries are build for)

Comment: @luffy: it is exactly what I installed, so you mean it is not installed properly, i.e. Qt mingw version does not need any pre-installation? I installed also VS 2015 express but nothing changed

Comment: try completely uninstalling Qt. Then reinstall using the link I gave you